# Standard streams vs. non-standard streams

Tags: java, c, unix, linux-kernel, stdin

The so-called **"standard streams"** in Linux are **stdin**, **stdout**, and **stderr**. But they must be called "standard" for a reason. **Are there non-standard streams?** And are these non-standard streams fundamentally treated differently by the kernel?

Comment: Basically, streams are just sequences of bytes. stdio (standard I/O) references those you said. But every TCP connection, every stream between two threads, every stream from drives, from devices in general, they all are streams. Often, primarily package-oriented systems (like UDP or USB) also are accessible as streams, an abstraction, to make access easier.  The difference is that every application on unix/linux/windows systems has at least those three (in, out, errout) by default, the others you have to create and access by your own means.

Comment: They're *standard* because the C Standard says they're defined in `<stdio.h>`. No other identifiers are used in this manner. C has no concept of "kernel", that's an implementation issue.

Comment: Is this a question about C, Java or the Linux kernel (which does not care about application programming language)?

Comment: They are the three streams that are "standard" to every process. Shells connect the three to the terminal (printer and keyboard, or serial port, or like now: virtual terminal connected to a screen and a keyboard). The other streams: you are responsible to open and close, and if you fork a program, you should usually close all other (non-std) streams.

Answer (score 2):

The standard streams are simply the ones ordinarily open when starting a new program in a new process.

Processes may open other streams, whether to regular files, devices (or pseudo-devices), network connections, or what have you. To the operating system kernel, other streams opened by a process are not fundamentally different from the standard streams.

When a shell executes a command, the shell is responsible for setting up the standard streams as it creates the new process and starts execution of the program. It does this through ordinary system calls to open or otherwise work with streams. If you write your own program to create a new process, it can configure the streams differently from standard, and the operating system will not care.

Linux is [Unix-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like), and [The Single Unix Specification](https://unix.org/version4/) has an section “stderr, stdin, stdout - standard I/O streams” which says:

> … At program start-up, three streams shall be predefined and need not be opened explicitly: *standard input* (for reading conventional input), *standard output* (for writing conventional output), and *standard error* (for writing diagnostic output)…

Comment: The standard streams are simply the ones ordinarily open when starting a new program in a new process.

Although this is mostly true, stderr is not always open at launch although its a rare site to not see it

Comment: @Imeguras: This answer does not say the standard streams are always open. it says they are ordinarily open. This is part of the Single Unix Specification, which says “At program start-up, three streams shall be predefined and need not be opened explicitly: *standard input* (for reading conventional input), *standard output* (for writing conventional output), and *standard error* (for writing diagnostic output).”

Comment: Oh i was distracted, you are right. I should start rereading stuff. I've read recently something about the specification being flimsy and up to interpretation, thats why i jumped at it without properly reading everything

Answer (score 0):

In Unix ideology, everything should either be a file or a directory.  This is why you can see your devices in /dev or your running processes in /proc. There are some exceptions depending on the implementation or distro. But everything you can "touch" or think as a "thing" is **typically** represented by a file

As JayC667 said a stream is just a sequence of bytes, which in the end is just a file. For example you can open a file (using fopen) and then use fprintf to write in the newly opened stream. There are many other examples of non-standard streams all typically contain a file handler, for standard ones, the file handler of stdin is 0, stdout 1, and stderr is 2; these don't change.  Using write() you can use these ids to write to any stream although since only these three are standard you mostly won't be hardcoding any number in, other than these three (as usual there are some exceptions).

Another thing that might help you understand the concept is, if you are on linux you can do `ps -ef | grep <program>` and then go to /proc/<pid>/fd to see the opened file descriptors. Tipically you will find the first two standard file descriptors(stdin, and stdout) along with other "non standard" ones

Comment: Actually in UNIX everything is a file, directories too: a directory is just a file containing "names" of other files.

Comment: well @mikyll98 for example, Unix domain sockets are not files, but they do appear in the filesystem. Theres also one or two third party softwares that will break the principle of "everything is a file"